# multiprocessing in python (going from a for loop to multiprocessing for loop)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a script that works.  It has a for loop that id like to improve the speed of by incorporating multiprocessing.

The code without multiprocessing is as follows:

```
    Symbol= Symbol[0:]   #slicing to coose which stocks to look at
    ################################for loop
    for item in Symbol:
        print item
        try:
            serious=web.DataReader([item], 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
            serious2=serious.loc[:, item].tolist()   #extract the column of 'Adj Close' 
            tickerlistori.append(item)
            valuemax = max(serious2)
            indexmax = serious2.index(max(serious2))
            valuemin = min(serious2)
            indexmin = serious2.index(min(serious2))         
            pricecurrent = serious2[-1]
            if valuemax>30 and valuemin<2 and pricecurrent<2.5:
                tickerlist.append(item)
                maxpricelist.append(valuemax)
                minpricelist.append(valuemin)
        except RemoteDataError: 
            pass
print tickerlist
```

The second code block below is "with parallel processing"

```
    Symbol= Symbol[0:]   #slicing to coose which stocks to look at
    ############ multi processing before the for loop
    def search1(Symbol):

        for item in Symbol:
            print item  #trying to see why the tickers are messed up
            try:
                serious=web.DataReader([item], 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
                serious2=serious.loc[:, item].tolist()   #extract the column of 'Adj Close' 
                tickerlistori.append(item)
                valuemax = max(serious2)
                indexmax = serious2.index(max(serious2))

                valuemin = min(serious2)
                indexmin = serious2.index(min(serious2))         


                pricecurrent = serious2[-1]

                if valuemax>30 and valuemin<2 and pricecurrent<2.5:
                    tickerlist.append(item)
                    maxpricelist.append(valuemax)
                    minpricelist.append(valuemin)
            except RemoteDataError: 
                pass


    pool = Pool(processes=4) 
    tickerlist = pool.map(search1, Symbol)
print tickerlist
```

The first one works fine but the second, although the code does run without error, the Symbol that gets fed into `pool.map(search1, Symbol)` doesn't seem right.

Thanks in advance.

(Symbol is just supposed to be a list of stock tickers)

## ---------------after making the changes tdelaney suggested

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas.io.data as web
from pandas.io.data import DataReader, SymbolWarning, RemoteDataError
from filesortfunct import filesort
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np
import math
from multiprocessing import Pool
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


#decide the two dates between which to look at stock prices
start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2/10/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2/25/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')

#intended to collect indeces and min/max prices
#global tickerlist, maxpricelist, minpricelist, tickerlistori
tickerlistori=[]    #list of stocks available from google finance
tickerlist=[]      
maxpricelist = []
minpricelist =[]


datanamelist= ['NYSE.csv']#,'NASDAQ.csv','AMEX.csv']
for each in datanamelist:


    #print each   #print out which stock exchange is being looked at
    dataname= each  #csv file from which to extract stock tickers
    new = 'new'


    df = pd.read_csv(dataname, sep=',')
    df = df[['Symbol']]

    df.to_csv(new+dataname, sep=',', index=False)

    x=open(new+dataname,'rb')    #convert it into a form more managable
    f = csv.reader(x) # csv is binary

    Symbol = zip(*f) 

    #print type(Symbol)   #list format

    Symbol=Symbol[0]   #pick out the first column

   # Symbol = Symbol[1:len(Symbol)]  #remove the first row "symbol" header
    Symbol = Symbol[3210:len(Symbol)] 


    Symbol= Symbol[0:]   #slicing to coose which stocks to look at
    #print Symbol


    def search1(item):
        print item  #trying to see why the tickers are messed up
        try:
            serious=web.DataReader([item], 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
            serious2=serious.loc[:, item].tolist()   #extract the column of 'Adj Close' 
            valuemax = max(serious2)
            indexmax = serious2.index(max(serious2))
            valuemin = min(serious2)
            indexmin = serious2.index(min(serious2))         
            pricecurrent = serious2[-1]

            if valuemax>30 and valuemin<2 and pricecurrent<2.5:
                return item, valuemax, valuemin
        except RemoteDataError: 
            pass


    pool = Pool(processes=4) 
    pool.start()
    for result in pool.map(search1, Symbol):

        if result:
            tickerlist.append(result[0])
            maxpricelist.append(result[1])
            minpricelist.append(result[2])

print tickerlist
```

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't seem right"? What is the expected result? What do you get instead?

Comment: You are using lots of global variables but remember that in multiprocessing, the pool workers use different address spaces and nobody, including the parent, sees the changes.

Comment: after making the changes @tdelaney, i get the following output:

Comment: with parallel processing (the block of code you suggested)  `([] XRM XUE XOXO XIN XRXXYLXPOXL YGEYOKUYDKNYZC YRDYPFAUYYELP ZENZBHYUMZFC ZPINZB^AYUMEZAYO ZOESZFZB^HZB^F ZTSZTRZBKZB^G)` but it should be `(XRM XRX XIN XL XOXO XPO XUE XYL YDKN AUY YZC YELP YGE YRD YOKU YPF YUM YUME ZFC ZAYO ZEN ZPIN ZBH ZB^A ZB^F ZB^G ZB^H ZBK ZOES ZTS ZF ZTR [])` , which is what i get from the original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got several problems:

- `map` will enumerate `Symbol` and run the worker for each. The worker doesn't need to enumerate it again in a for loop
- You update global lists... but those lists are global to the subprocess. The parent never sees them

Here's an update

```
Symbol= Symbol[0:]   #slicing to coose which stocks to look at
############ multi processing before the for loop
def search1(item):
    print item  #trying to see why the tickers are messed up
    try:
        serious=web.DataReader([item], 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
        serious2=serious.loc[:, item].tolist()   #extract the column of 'Adj Close' 
        valuemax = max(serious2)
        indexmax = serious2.index(max(serious2))
        valuemin = min(serious2)
        indexmin = serious2.index(min(serious2))         
        pricecurrent = serious2[-1]

        if valuemax>30 and valuemin<2 and pricecurrent<2.5:
            return item, valuemax, valuemin
    except RemoteDataError: 
        pass


pool = Pool(processes=4) 
for result in pool.map(search1, Symbol):
    if result:
            tickerlist.append(result[0])
            maxpricelist.append(result[1])
            minpricelist.append(result[2])
print tickerlist
```

Comment: thank you so much for help but i get the following error message:`AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute 'start`

Comment: i will post the entirety of my code after i did what you told me to do

Comment: My bad... you don't need the start. I've used Pool a thousand times and then today... maybe i need a nap.

Comment: without parallel processing i get the following  `(XRM
XRX
XIN
XL
XOXO
XPO
XUE
XYL
YDKN
AUY
YZC
YELP
YGE
YRD
YOKU
YPF
YUM
YUME
ZFC
ZAYO
ZEN
ZPIN
ZBH
ZB^A
ZB^F
ZB^G
ZB^H
ZBK
ZOES
ZTS
ZF
ZTR
[])`

Comment: with parallel processing (the block of code you suggested)  `[]
XRM
XUE
XOXO
XIN
XRXXYLXPOXL



YGEYOKUYDKNYZC



YRDYPFAUYYELP



ZENZBHYUMZFC



ZPINZB^AYUMEZAYO



ZOESZFZB^HZB^F



ZTSZTRZBKZB^G`

Comment: Since it isn't a runnable example, I can't say for sure, but... the tickers are printed on multiple lines? I think that's just the `print item` line in the worker. The processes are fighting for stdout. Comment it out to see if it goes away. `[]` probably means that `if valuemax>30 and valuemin<2 and pricecurrent<2.5` vetoed all of the symbols. I think `valuemax` etc... are still strings. You need to convert strings to ints and floats before the `max` operation and before the `if`.

Comment: as @tdelaney suggested comment out print item and any other print statement used except print tickerlist . Code provided by him should work just fine.

Comment: hmm yeah. in terms of the final output, it does print out the correct list of tickers.  thanks!